# Undefined sequence error related to math

Tags: errors

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathtools}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
\section{The intuitive Limit}

\begin{defn}
The line $x = a$ is said to be a \textit{vertical asymptote} for $f(x)$ if either of the one sided limits $x \longrightarrow a^+$ or x $\longrightarrow a^-$ is infinite; that is, if
\begin{center}
$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to a^{\pm}}} f(x) = \infty,$\space\space or \space\space$\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to a^{\pm}}} f(x) = - \infty$
\end{center}
\end{defn}

\begin{prop}
Consider the rational function $f(x) = \frac{a_nx^n\, +\, \dots\, +\, a_1x\, +\, a_0}{b_mx^m\, +\, \dots\, +\, b_1x\, +\, b_0 }$.\
\begin{enumerate}
\item If $n > m$ then $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \pm\infty}} f(x) = \pm\infty$, with the sign dependent on the sign of $a_n/b_m$
\item If $n < m$ then $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \pm\infty}} f(x) = 0$
\item If $n = m$ then $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to \pm\infty}} f(x) = \frac{a_n}{b_m}$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{prop}

\section{The Rigorous Limit}

\begin{defn}
Suppose that $c, L \in \R$ is an open interval containing $c$ If $f : I \to \R$, we say that the \textbf{limit of f as x approaches c is L}, and write
\begin{center}
$\lim{x \to c} f(x) = L$,
\end{center} 
if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $0 < \vert x - c \rvert < \delta$ then $\lvert f(x) - l \rvert < \varepsilon$.\ In terms of quantifiers:
\begin{center}
$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, \forall x \in \R (0 < \lvert x - c \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(x) - L \rvert < \varepsilon)$.
\end{center}
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

The problem is occurring in the "The rigorous limit" section where the definition is giving me the “Undefined control sequence” error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You need something like `\newcommand*{\R}{\mathbb{R}}`. You can add it before `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

I took the opportunity to improve and simplify a bit your code:

I don't see why you put your formulæ in a `center`  environment instead of using the  `\[ ... \]` construct.

Another point is that, in my opinion, in an italic text, the enumerate labels should be in upshape, which is easy to obtain with `enumitem

Last, I used `\mfrac` (medium-size fraction) from `nccmath`, which looks better then `\tfrac` in this context. Please note that `nccmath`has to be loadede *before* `mathtools`, and that you don't have to load `amsmath` if you load the former, as it is an extension of amsmath.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{nccmath, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]

\def\R{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}
\section{The intuitive Limit}

\begin{defn}
The line $x = a$ is said to be a \textit{vertical asymptote} for $f(x)$ if either of the one sided limits $x \longrightarrow a^+$ or x $\longrightarrow a^-$ is infinite; that is, if
\[ \lim_{x \to a^{\pm}} f(x) = \infty,\quad\text{or} \quad\lim_{x \to a^{\pm}} f(x) = - \infty \]
\end{defn}

\begin{prop}
Consider the rational function $f(x) = \mfrac{a_nx^n\, +\, \dots\, +\, a_1x\, +\, a_0}{b_mx^m\, +\, \dots\, +\, b_1x\, +\, b_0 }$.\
\begin{enumerate}[font=\upshape]
\item If $n > m$ then $\lim\limits_{x \to \pm\infty} f(x) = \pm\infty$, with the sign dependent on the sign of $a_n/b_m$
\item If $n < m$ then $\lim\limits_{x \to \pm\infty} f(x) = 0$
\item If $n = m$ then $\lim\limits_{x \to \pm\infty} f(x) = \dfrac{a_n}{b_m}$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{prop}

\section{The Rigorous Limit}

\begin{defn}
Suppose that $c, L \in \R$ is an open interval containing $c$ If $f : I \to \R$, we say that the \textbf{limit of f as x approaches c is L}, and write
\[ \lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L, \]
if for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $0 < \vert x - c \rvert < \delta$ then $\lvert f(x) - l \rvert < \varepsilon$.\ In terms of quantifiers:
\[ \forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, \forall x \in \R (0 < \lvert x - c \rvert < \delta \implies \lvert f(x) - L \rvert < \varepsilon). \]
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. i just started to learn latex today so haven't caught up that much.

Comment: Belated congratulations on passing the 200k rep mark!

Comment: You could also remove `\displaystyle` (that, by the way, doesn't take an argument) in favor of `\limits`.

Comment: @egreg: Quite judicious. I've updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The precise error message is:

```
./doc.tex:35: Undefined control sequence.
l.35 Suppose that $c, L \in \R
                              $ is an open interval containing $c$ If $f : I...
```

Note the line break after `\R`. This means that TeX had read until this `\R`, but not later when he found this error. You can infer that the undefined control sequence is `\R`. Indeed, it is not defined in your document. One way to define it is to put:

```latex
\newcommand*{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
```

before `\begin{document}`, which uses the `\mathbb` command from `amsfonts`, which is a package that is loaded by `amssymb`. The result with `\mathbb` is as follows:

[image]

Another way would be to use:

```latex
\newcommand*{\R}{\mathbf{R}}
```

`\mathbf` gives a bold R, like this:

[image]

Which one to use among these two is a matter of taste. There would be a third way with the `bm` package:

```latex
\newcommand*{\R}{\bm{R}}
```

but note that in this case, the bold R would be in italics; I am not sure this is desirable in this context:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not finding the command `\R`. Put at preamble: `\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}`, and it will work.

Comment: Also `\lim{x \to c}` should be `\lim_{x \to c}`